# Does orgasm cause a dopamine crash?

Tags: sex, neurotransmitter

There's some theory around that orgasm will cause a dopamine surge and drop, and that this can lead to a period of low mood or depression. A come down.

Is this true, does orgasm have a negative psychological consequence ?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your last question, I very much doubt it's true in general. It does have unplesant effects in some people though. Form [a popsci account](http://www.nytimes.com/2009/01/20/health/views/20mind.html)

> He [a psychoanalyst] was puzzled about a 24-year-old man whom he viewed as psychiatrically healthy except for intense depression that lasted for several hours after sex. [...] Could it be that some patients have particularly strong rebound activity in the amygdala after orgasm that makes them feel bad?

And this [post-coital dysphoria can happen to women too](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4721025/), for which there is some prevalence data:

> Forty‐six percent of respondents reported experiencing PCD symptoms at least once in their lifetime with 5.1% experiencing PCD symptoms a few times within the past 4 weeks.

---

"No sex before game day" was a tenet in some sports psychology/physiology corners, but more recent research failed to find significant differences of sex acts on mental performance... at least in (healthy) athletes. A [2016 review notes](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fphys.2016.00246/full)

> Despite the major differences found in the recovery phase, where higher values of HR [heart rate] were found 2 h after sexual intercourse, no significant differences were found in workload achieved and in mental concentration of the athletes.

And, yeah, I know sex doesn't necessarily mean orgasm, but it seems close enough to mention.